# Can someone tell me what's wrong with mi Task.await?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, process, elixir

Have this code I expect to work on child doing the is_prime function for the given number_list and return the result, but I'm having issues to retrieve the result from the Task.await method.

```
defmodule LeaderWorker do
  def start() do
    children = [{Task.Supervisor,
      name: Task.SomeThingSupervisor,
    }]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end

  def run(number_list, num_workers) do
    results =
      number_list
      |> Task.async_stream(&check_prime/1, max_concurrency: num_workers)
      |> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)

    IO.inspect(results)
  end

  def check_prime(number) do
    prime = is_prime(number)
    IO.inspect({number, prime})
    {number, prime}
  end

  def is_prime(number) when number <= 1 do
    false
  end

  def is_prime(number) do
    not Enum.any?(2..(div(number, 2)), &(&1 != 1 and rem(number, &1) == 0))
  end
end

LeaderWorker.start()
number_list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
LeaderWorker.run(number_list, 4)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
 elixir .\clean.ex
{2, false}
{3, true}
{4, false}
{5, true}
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Task.await/2    

    The following arguments were given to Task.await/2:

        # 1
        {:ok, {2, false}}

        # 2
        5000

    Attempted function clauses (showing 1 out of 1):

        def await(%Task{ref: ref, owner: owner} = task, timeout) when timeout == :infinity or is_integer(timeout) and timeout >= 0

    (elixir 1.16.2) Task.await/2
    (elixir 1.16.2) lib/enum.ex:1708: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
    (elixir 1.16.2) lib/enum.ex:4396: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
    (elixir 1.16.2) lib/task/supervised.ex:386: Task.Supervised.stream_deliver/7
    (elixir 1.16.2) lib/enum.ex:4396: Enum.map/2
    clean.ex:14: LeaderWorker.run/2
    clean.ex:36: (file)
```

I'm trying to get a solution for that problem to get the {number, boolean} list that I should be having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per a documentation for [Task.async_stream/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async_stream/3),

> When streamed, each task will emit `{:ok, value}` upon successful completion […]

That said, `Task.await/1` has nothing to do with this code. The result of a call to `Task.async_stream/3` would be a `Stream`, and each element of this stream would hang up until the task is completed, and then return `{:ok, result}` to the stream. Each task will be awaited until the result of its execution becomes available in the stream.

If you want to just spit out the results, consider using [`Stream.run/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#run/1).

```elixir
  number_list
  |> Task.async_stream(&check_prime/1, max_concurrency: num_workers)
  |> Stream.each(&IO.inspect/1) # outputs each task result
  |> Stream.run()
```

If you need the results themselves, collect them

```elixir
  number_list
  |> Task.async_stream(&check_prime/1, max_concurrency: num_workers)
  |> Stream.map(fn {:ok, {value, prime?}} -> {prime?, value} end)
  |> Enum.to_list()
  |> IO.inspect(label: "Results")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your `run` function like this:

```
  def run(number_list, num_workers) do
    stream =
      number_list
      |> Task.async_stream(&check_prime/1, max_concurrency: num_workers)

    Enum.reduce(stream, %{}, fn {number, prime}, acc -> Map.put(acc, number, prime) end)
  end
```

since you are using a stream, you need to collect somehow the items instead of plainly awaiting for results, `reduce` here does the trick, but someone please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Another option would be to simple call Enum.map and do something there, for example:

```
  def run(number_list, num_workers) do
    results =
      number_list
      |> Task.async_stream(&check_prime/1, max_concurrency: num_workers)

    Enum.each(results, fn {:ok, p} -> IO.inspect(p) end)
  end
```

With any of these changes you will get the following result as output:

```
{2, false}
{3, true}
{5, true}
{4, false}
{6, false}
{7, true}
{8, false}
{9, false}
{10, false}
{11, true}
```

The caveat with this solution is that you are not really using the result of reduce, but just collecting the output, so there may be more efficient solutions

Comment: `Task.async_stream/1` awaits for the results on its own, see my answer for details.